# Codeigniter Datamapper order by relation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Good afternoon,

I am using Datamapper Overzealous Edition for Codeigniter to build a football league website. All of my fixtures are stored within a database table with the following format:

```
ID     Competition_id    Home_team_id    Away_team_id    Etc...
```

As you guessed, my competitions table has the following format:

```
ID    Name
```

When I get my fixtures from the database, I would like to order them by the related competitions name so for example, I would use the following:

```
$fixtures = new fixtures();
$fixtures->order_by('competition/name','asc')->get();
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the order_by function does not support this form of syntax. Can anybody come up with a clean way to accomplish this? All I can think of is manually placing every fixture into an array and ordering that way but that would seem like alot of redundant code!

Many thanks in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to join the table and sort on the field needed.

```
$fixtures = new fixtures();
$fixtures->include_related('competition', 'name', true)->order_by('competition_name', 'ASC')->get();
```